# Unable to get Alert Pop-Up on IE...Works fine in Firefox,Chrome etc.?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, emptydatatext

I am trying to get pop-up block when there is no text/blank space. It is working fine in Firefox, Chrome &Safari.

Please check below code in my JavaScript file-:

```
function submitQuestion(URL,docId,errorMessage)
{
var question = $('textField').value;
if(!question.blank())
{
var submitForm = $("question-form");
submitForm.action = URL+"docId="+docId+"&question="+encodeURIComponent(question);
//alert(submitForm.action);
submitForm.submit();
}
else
{
alert(errorMessage);
return false;
}
}
```

Above function works fine in Firefox,Safari &Chrome as when there is nothing in textbox (i.e. empty/blank) then it goes to else &prompt errorMessage as a pop-up but in IE, it doesn't go to else &errorMessage pop-up never come.

Please check below code for my forntend form-:

```
<form method="POST" id="question-form" onsubmit="return submitQuestion('https://localhost/question-post!input.jspa?','ABC12','Enter your question!');">
                <span class="fieldwrap">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Ask customers about this document" value="" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" class="questionInputField" id="textField">
                </span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="question-submit" class="widget-div clearfix">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit question to the portal" class="questionSubmitFormButton">

                    </div>
                </div>  

            </form>
```

What happened here in IE is it will take placeholder as a value for text field when we didn't provide any i.e. When we keep text field empty or blank then it will take placeholder as a text field value &instead of giving pop-up alert, it goes to if loop which should not be a case.

Comment: On what event do you do this? Do NOT submit a form in the submit event - please show where and how you call this code

Answer (score 0):

To access the value of the textField using jQuery, you should use val() instead of value.

```
var question = $('textField').val();
if (question != '') {
 //
}
else {
 //
}
```

Below is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>EXAMPLE</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function submitQuestion(URL, docId, errorMessage) {
            var question = $('#textField').val();
            if (question.trim() != "") {
                var submitForm = $("#question-form");
                submitForm.attr("action", URL + "docId=" + docId + "&question=" + encodeURIComponent(question));
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert(errorMessage);
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" id="question-form" onsubmit="return submitQuestion('https://localhost/question-post!input.jspa?','ABC12','Enter your question!');">
        <span class="fieldwrap">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ask customers about this document" value="" maxlength="255" autocomplete="off" class="questionInputField" id="textField">
        </span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="question-submit" class="widget-div clearfix">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit question to the portal" class="questionSubmitFormButton">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I have written javascript. can you please tell me for javascript as .val() gives me blank page after clicking submit.